# CSS Dropdown Menu Styling

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I get rid of the horizontal borders that divide each menu item per the following example but maintain the overall outer border of the active menu:

http://jsfiddle.net/tdJnS/

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove border-top from the li -> a.

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tdJnS/1/)** here

**CSS** changes below,

```
ul#navmenu-h li:hover li a,
ul#navmenu-h li.iehover li a {
 /*border-top: 1px solid #EEEEEE;*/  <-- Commented
...
...
```

and

```
ul#navmenu-h li:hover a,
ul#navmenu-h li.iehover a
{
 /*border-top: 1px solid #EEEEEE;*/  <-- Commented
 ...
 ...
```

**Edit:**

It should work if you add a border to `ul` and remove the `margin-left: -1` and `margin-top: -1` from the `li > a`.

Also Please note that removing margin's would give a different feel from what you had before.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/tdJnS/23/)** here

```
/*newly added - Change to any color to #EEEEEE if that is what you want */
ul#navmenu-h ul    
{
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

and Commented below,

```
ul#navmenu-h li:hover li a,
ul#navmenu-h li.iehover li a {
 /*border-top: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
 border-right: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
 border-left: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
  margin-left: -1px; */


ul#navmenu-h li:hover a,
ul#navmenu-h li.iehover a
{
 /*border-top: 1px solid #EEEEEE;*/
 /*margin-top: -1px;*/
```

Comment: Hi, I still do need the top border for uppermost main menu item so it looks like a tab select.

Comment: @JaJ: See my edit. Basically added border for ul and removed margin left and top.

Answer (score 3):

Remove border-top from this:

```
ul#navmenu-h li.iehover li a {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
 border-right: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
 border-left: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
 margin-left: -1px; 

 float: none; 
 background: #FFF;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 10px; 
}
```

Comment: Hi, that didn't do it unless I'm missing somethin.  See my update for final output example (facebook like tab menu).

Comment: There's a second one you also have to remove